# What RPC protocols does AppEngine support for connecting to Compute Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, sockets, rpc, spdy, google-compute-engine

Now that Compute Engine is open to the public, what protocols besides HTTP can you use from AppEngine to connect to backend Compute Engine servers?

Also, Ilya Grigorik has been advocating using SPDY for the backend, but last year  he pointed out that AppEngine not does support this (http://www.igvita.com/2012/01/18/building-a-modern-web-stack-for-the-realtime-web/). Has this changed or are there plans to add support for this in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any TCP or UDP protocol to talk between App Engine and Compute Engine. How? Socket API.

For Java:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/overview

For Python:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/overview

You would still need to implement the protocol over TCP or UDP, or find a library that does it for you.